# Dismissing bottomViewcontroller on value change swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an application in which a bottomSheet viewcontroller is presented at different states that is, if I am search a location, I get a particular bottomsheet etc. This particular bottom Sheet appears when there is a negative value and the way to clear that is to click on a `resolve Button` which turns the negative value to zero and after returning to the `Main viewcontroller`, the negative `bottom sheet` controller is suppose to disapear which is what I am unable to do. I called the `bottom sheet` function in my view `didLoad` so as to maintain state and if I try calling it in `viewDidAppear`, the state is not maintained but the negative `bottom sheet` goes away beacause the `view controller` realizes that the value is not a negative.

My question now is how can I make the `Main viewcontroller` realize that the value has returned to zero so that the `that particular bottom sheet` which is a member of `bottom ViewController` is not suppose to appear.

though if I leave the `MainViewController` to another `ViewController` and go back to `MainViewController`, everything is fine beacse `viewdidLoad` is called again.

my codes are highlighted below

```
fileprivate func setupBottomSheets() {
   outstandingPay = UIStoryboard.bottomSheet
            .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: OutStandingPaymentVC.className) as? OutStandingPaymentVC

   _ = outstandingPay.view
   bottomDrawer.outstandingVC = outstandingPay

   infoVc = UIStoryboard.bottomSheet
            .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: InfoViewController.className)
            as? InfoViewController

   _ = infoVc.view
}
```

in my presenter

```
func start() {
    if source.getWalletBalance() >= 0 {
         view?.setOutstandingPayView(visible: false, walletBalance: 0)
    } else {
         view?.setOutstandingPayView(visible: true, walletBalance: source.getWalletBalance())
    }
}

func navigationButtonPressed() {
    if source.getWalletBalance() < 0 {
        view?.setOutstandingPayView(visible: true, walletBalance: 0)
    } else {
        view?.setOutstandingPayView(visible: false, walletBalance: source.getWalletBalance())
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show some more code to see where and when you call those functions.

Comment: the buttomSheet is called in `var bottomDrawer: BottomSheetViewController! {didSet {setupBottomSheets()}}`

Comment: I solved it using NotificationCenter.